# Display Large Base64 Image MVC 4 DOTNET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First I have some images stored as Binary on SSMS these images are stored in byte format of byte size above 10K.

So far I have tried a couple techniques that are going to be listed below.

**Note I have read that base64 images when rendering usually are used for small base type images for instances 64 by 64.**

**The issue** is not to convert the images into to base64 but is to find a way where I request the image from the **DB** one by one using Jquery then add the image base64 to the Image Attribute on the DOM.

//Note: Images requested are converted to base64 from the api side but the image binary may be large so the Base64 always comes back large on the browser img src attribute when inspect says file size too large.

Please don't point that I said its use for small images am looking for a solution where someone made it work with larger images.

Resizing not an option for it kills the document resolution an how it needs to be viewed. Though if there is a solution can you point me it. I have tried to resize the image just to let you be aware but the images will be pix elated on presentation if stretch which would be obvious.

**Remember am asking for a better approach or if I can load multiple images on the dom using Jquery with a large Base64.**

I also know that i can show a list of the Images using links then allow the user to click the link to view that specific image.

I am using Dotnet 4.5 MVC

Code for what I have Tried:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".my-image-tag").each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
        var apiUrl = "www.xxxx.com";
        console.log(
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: apiUrl ,
                data: { 'Id': img.attr('data-id') },
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.Image);
                img.attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data.Image);
            }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                ///Need a Error Logger Page
            })
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just serve the images as binary, rather than the round-trip to base64? You can just set src tags on the images to point to your API server rather than trying to download base64 and creating data URLs. Yes, you can use data URLs to embed images in HTML on the server but if you're doing this on the client there's no benefit at all, and in the HTTP/2 world there's little benefit to the embedding on the server side either.

Comment: Hey @Rup Remember the Images are not stored in folder they are being retrieved from the DB and then post to the client application. Are you saying I can do this `<img src="api.xxxx.com/id"/>` and this will read the binary as is

Comment: @DavidWhite, it's more easy than it seems to be. Returning an image from server in your code, is basically writing an array of bytes in the response. The img tag has no idea where those bytes came from (a database, a file, etc) but it works.

Comment: @derloopkat Am trying understand give me a sec your saying that the this url `api.xxxx.com/id` will go to my method on the API application `GetImage(int id)` then when i select the array of bytes from my DB it will return those bytes an the image tag will automatically render that image. I can't conceptualize this please explain

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. I did this with Asp.Net webforms to serve images from DB and I guess it's quite similar in MVC. My Html code looked like `<img src="http://localhost/getImage.aspx?name=cars20" />`. Then in my `getImage.aspx` I was going to DB and writing the bytes for the image in the response. Later on I've also used Http Handlers to achieve the same as returning an image from webform is a bit hacky. Remember to specify correct mime type in the response.

Comment: Tried @derloopkat didn't work don't know Technology Dotnet use in WEbforms to allow that to work

Comment: @DavidWhite, try to find working example.

Comment: There wasn't any big issue with my way or method I found out that when I was converting the binary to save to the DB I was using `Encoding.Default` in DotNet to get the binary from the upload side it throw off the binary for the base64 image. I resolve this by using ` `Convert.FromBase64String(var.Image);` to create the binary then `Convert.ToBase64String(var.Image);` use to get the correct base64 Okay

Answer (score 2):

As Rup suggested in a comment your best bet may be to make a method in your API that serves the image.

```
<img src="/controller/getimage/imagename">
```

Then in your controller something like...

```
public ActionResult getimage(string imagename)
{
   var data = //call database to get image data
   var file = //convert data into File "image/jpeg" or whatever file type you use
   return file;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how would I reference the return file type on the image tag `img.attr('src', data.File);` will it just render just like that out the box or do i need to convert the file pass over from the API.

Comment: When the MVC action replies with a file it functions exactly as if it were an image file on the server. As listed above you should just need to set the source to the controller action